# What happens to Transactions in the pool of a non-mining node?

Tags: transactions

Both incoming and local transactions are validated and added to the transaction pool.  A mining node pulls from the Tx pool to build blocks. What does a **non**-mining node do with the transactions in the pool?

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Ethereum. In all blockchains, all nodes publish all transactions they receive, to their peers. So some mining node will hear about the transaction at some time and include it in a block. That is my understanding.